# Returning a character element from a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, return, character, element

I have a method that returns a character element from a two dimensional array of strings based on the input coordinate parameters.

```
public BattleShips(GameConfiguration config, Player player1, Player player2) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.config = config;
    this.myBoardPlayer1= new char[20][20];
    this.myBoardPlayer2= new char[20][20];
}
protected char getCellState(int player, int x, int y) {
    if (isValidCoordinate(x,y) == true){
        if (player == 0){
            return this.myBoardPlayer1[x][y];
        }
        else if (player == 1){
            return this.myBoardPlayer2[x][y];
        }
    }
    else {
        return (char) -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code results in eclipse telling me the method getCellState() isn't returning a result of type char even when i have initialized the instance variables, myBoardPlayer1 and myBoardPlayer2 as char[20][20] in the constructor.

So my question: is this correct the return method for a character element in an array?
Alternatively, is this.myBoardPlayer1[x][y] not considered a character? If not how can I change my code so that getCellState() returns whatever character value this.myBoardPlayer1[x][y] has?

Comment: return depends upon this protected "char" getCellState, not what instance variable you have. So you must return a 'char' in every if and else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler cannot prove that your `getCellState()` will *always* return something (bit of a misleading compiler error, I suppose).

*You* might know that `player` is either `0` or `1` if `isValidCoordinate()` returns `true`, but the compiler can't read your mind. It notices that you haven't said what to return in the case that `isValidCoordinate()` returns `true` and `player` **isn't** `0` or `1` and complains, because a method that returns something must be guaranteed to return something in all cases, and to the compiler, there are some cases where the method isn't defined to return something.

So you can either change that `else if` to a regular `else`, or add another `else` case to define what will happen if `isValidCoordinate()` returns `true` and `player` isn't `0` or `1`.